# MYSQL SUM durations within consecutive hours

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range, gaps-and-islands, mysql-5.6

Using an older version of MySQL where the WITH clause is not valid.

Starting with a table:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| person | start_time          | end_time            |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 20:00:00 | 2020-02-27 20:59:59 |
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 |
| Alice  | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | 2020-02-28 00:59:59 |
| Alice  | 2020-02-28 01:00:00 | 2020-02-28 01:59:59 |
| Bob    | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 |
| Cindy  | 2020-02-28 02:00:00 | 2020-02-28 02:59:59 |
| Cindy  | 2020-02-28 03:00:00 | 2020-02-28 03:36:59 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I'd like a query to sum all durations-per-person that fall within an hour of each other.

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| person | start_time          | end_time            | duration |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 20:00:00 | 2020-02-27 20:59:59 |     3599 |
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-28 01:59:59 |     8064 |
| Bob    | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 |      899 |
| Cindy  | 2020-02-28 02:00:00 | 2020-02-28 03:36:59 |     5806 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: This kind of task is really uneasy in a database that does not implement recursive queries.

Comment: Should `Bob` `end_time` be `2020-02-27 23:59:59`

Comment: Thanks Peter. I corrected it in the example.

Comment: Do not think you can do that in a single query. Make a procedure and inside the procedure use cursor to loop through the rows and calculate the duration per user. Store the result in temp table and return the result set at the end of the procedure. Try it out and if you have problems, post a question with code.

Comment: @slaakso Why not?

Comment: @Strawberry Let me rephrase this. Apart from fun academic exercise, in order to make the single query work in all cases (overlapping times etc), the query might be possible, but becomes rather complex and hard to maintain. We should promote good solutions and do believe that in a case like this, a cursor is a good choise.

Comment: @slaakso that's quite a significant 'rephrasing'. Nonetheless, it's not a position with which I agree

Comment: @Strawberry That is fine as it is an opinion based topic. Do you have a single query that works reliably?

Comment: @slaakso - I might be mistaken, but I believe my alternative solution works reliably. In the event that it doesn't, I'm nevetheless confident that it can be rewritten to work reliably using the extended functionality afforded by versions 8.0+

Comment: @Strawberry, CTE's would certainly make things easier. Would personally do such a query with a cursor for easier maintenance and portability, but commend (+1) your effort for the query.

Comment: @GMB what troubles me is that in an uneasy problem the mostly up-voted answer is written only for versions of MySQL prior 8.0 (meaning covering less versions) and is more complicated (to my opinion). Now to your opinion, do you think that sometimes the "correct answer" is simply a matter of popularity? or any other factor... perhaps it is a coding x-factor thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. - although, as written, this solution is exclusively for versions of MySQL prior to 8.0...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(person VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,start_time DATETIME NOT NULL
,end_time DATETIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(person,start_time)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Alice','2020-02-27 20:00:00','2020-02-27 20:59:59'),
('Alice','2020-02-27 23:45:00','2020-02-27 23:59:59'),
('Alice','2020-02-28 00:00:00','2020-02-28 00:59:59'),
('Alice','2020-02-28 01:00:00','2020-02-28 01:59:59'),
('Bob','2020-02-27 23:45:00','2020-02-27 23:59:59'),
('Cindy','2020-02-28 02:00:00','2020-02-28 02:59:59'),
('Cindy','2020-02-28 03:00:00','2020-02-28 03:36:59');

SELECT person
     , MIN(start_time) start_time
     , MAX(end_time) end_time
     , SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time))) delta 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN person = @prev_person 
                   THEN CASE WHEN start_time <= @prev_end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
                             THEN @i:=@i 
                             ELSE @i:=@i+1 END 
                   ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev_person := person
            , @prev_end_time := end_time
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev_person := null, @prev_end_time := null, @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY person
            , start_time
     ) a
 GROUP  
    BY person,i;
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| person | start_time          | end_time            | delta |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 20:00:00 | 2020-02-27 20:59:59 |  3599 |
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-28 01:59:59 |  8097 |
| Bob    | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 |   899 |
| Cindy  | 2020-02-28 02:00:00 | 2020-02-28 03:36:59 |  5818 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

FWIW, I think rewriting the query this way renders it 'version agnostic', i.e. impervious to the fair accusation that the order of evaluation of elements is not guaranteed - but I might be wrong. Regardless, in MySQL 8.0+ the below can be rewritten with the extended functionality afforded by that version.

```
SELECT person
     , MIN(start_time) start_time
     , MAX(end_time) end_time
     , SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time))) delta 
  FROM 
  ( SELECT * FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN person = @prev_person 
                   THEN CASE WHEN start_time <= @prev_end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
                             THEN @i:=@i 
                             ELSE @i:=@i+1 END 
                   ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev_person := person
            , @prev_end_time := end_time
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev_person := null, @prev_end_time := null, @i:=0) vars 
     ) k
      ORDER 
                BY person
            , start_time
     ) a
 GROUP  
    BY person,i;
```

Comment: Good job emulating window functions, +1. But this: `CASE WHEN person = @prev_person ... END i, @prev_person := person` is always unsafe, since MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of elements in the `SELECT` clause. I think you it would take a more complex `CASE` expression to manage that.

Answer (score 1):

An example query that will provide such a result-set is:

```
SELECT t.person,t.start_time,t.end_time,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t.end_time)) AS duration,
IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test t1
WHERE t1.start_time=TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,1,t.end_time) 
OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t1.end_time)=-1),1,0) AS continuous
FROM test t
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t.end_time) 
BETWEEN 0 AND 3599 
GROUP BY t.person,continuous
ORDER BY t.person,t.start_time;
```

Which is the same as

```
SELECT t.person,t.start_time,t.end_time,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t.end_time)) AS duration,
IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test t1
WHERE t1.start_time=TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,1,t.end_time) 
OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.end_time,t.start_time)=1),1,0) AS continuous
FROM test t
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t.end_time) 
BETWEEN 0 AND 3599 
GROUP BY t.person,continuous
ORDER BY t.person,t.start_time;
```

Check both queries in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/989a22a/37)

**EDIT**

Based on @Strawberry's comment the above queries need to be re-writen with a minor change.

```
SELECT t.person,t.start_time,t.end_time,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t.end_time)) AS duration,
IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test t1
WHERE t1.start_time=TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,1,t.end_time) 
OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t1.end_time)=-1),1,0) AS continuous
FROM test t
GROUP BY t.person,continuous
ORDER BY t.person,t.start_time;
```

Which is the same as

```
SELECT t.person,t.start_time,t.end_time,
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.start_time,t.end_time)) AS duration,
IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test t1
WHERE t1.start_time=TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,1,t.end_time) 
OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t1.end_time,t.start_time)=1),1,0) AS continuous
FROM test t
GROUP BY t.person,continuous
ORDER BY t.person,t.start_time;
```

Check both queries in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa29b1/5)

Comment: If Cindy has a record that's within one hour of 2020-02-28 03:36:59, but not within 2020-02-28 02:59:59, I imagine this would still want to be counted as one continuous periiod, but I don't think your query does that.

Comment: you mean that if Cindy had another record with `start_time` `2020-02-28 03:37:00` it would count as continuous. But if it was `2020-02-28 03:37:01` it would not. I think this is quite obvious.

Comment: I mean with a start time between 04:00:00 and 04:37:00

Comment: @Strawberry this is not `continuous` meaning that there was a 25 minute break. So it will be calculated in a single row like `Alice`

Comment: Well, just to make the OP aware of the discrepancy; I suppose it's up to them to clarify the meaning of 'within consecutive hours' if they want to.

Comment: @Strawberry by the way it was not needed to remove the back-ticks. Was it wrong that they were used?

Comment: It was illegible. Of course, you're entitled to disagree, but I think it's fair to say that there's a consensus on this site that backticks do not aid comprehension, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Strawberry for you having a break is considered `consecutive`? I see the example Fiddle provided does bring up the result the OP wants but only you have a different opinion regarding `consecutive`, anyway whatever mate...

Comment: Hm, I think you've missed my point. But, to be fair, I think I haven't explained it very well.

Comment: Perhaps, this is clearer. I've tweaked and extended your data set. The two queries provide different results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa29b1/3

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the point, that only needs to just comment one line in that query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa29b1/4

Comment: @Strawberry to tell you the truth i was mislead by this phrase `I'd like a query to sum all durations-per-person that fall within an hour of each other.`. In the beginning i thought that each individual record needed to have `start_time` and `end_time` within the hour so that is why the part of 3599 seconds was used.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting in a single query wasn't easy for me but I did it with self `LEFT JOIN` the table and a bunch of conditions in `ON` clause

```
SELECT A.Person,
       MIN(A.start_time) AS start_time,
       MAX(A.end_time) AS end_time,
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(A.end_time),MIN(A.start_time)))  Duration,
       CASE WHEN B.person IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chk 
FROM my_table A
LEFT JOIN my_table B 
ON A.person=B.person 
AND A.start_time - INTERVAL 1 HOUR < B.end_time -- when A.start_time minus 1 hour is smaller than B.end_time
AND A.end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR > B.start_time -- when A.end_time plus 1 hour is bigger than B.start_time 
AND A.start_time <> B.start_time -- when A.start_time is not same as B.start_time 
GROUP BY A.person,chk;
```

The base query was this:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN b.person IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chk
FROM my_table a LEFT JOIN my_table b 
ON a.person=b.person 
AND a.start_time - INTERVAL 1 HOUR < b.end_time
AND a.end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR > b.start_time
AND a.start_time <> b.start_time;
```

which return the following result:

```
+ ------ + ------------------- + ------------------- + ------ + ------------------- + ------------------- + --- +
| person | start_time          | end_time            | person | start_time          | end_time            | chk |
+ ------ + ------------------- + ------------------- + ------ + ------------------- + ------------------- + --- +
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 20:00:00 | 2020-02-27 20:59:59 | NULL   |        NULL         |        NULL         | 0   |
| Alice  | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | 2020-02-28 00:59:59 | Alice  | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 | 1   |
| Alice  | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 | Alice  | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | 2020-02-28 00:59:59 | 1   |
| Alice  | 2020-02-28 01:00:00 | 2020-02-28 01:59:59 | Alice  | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | 2020-02-28 00:59:59 | 1   |
| Alice  | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | 2020-02-28 00:59:59 | Alice  | 2020-02-28 01:00:00 | 2020-02-28 01:59:59 | 1   |
| Bob    | 2020-02-27 23:45:00 | 2020-02-27 23:59:59 | NULL   |        NULL         |        NULL         | 0   |
| Cindy  | 2020-02-28 03:00:00 | 2020-02-28 03:36:59 | Cindy  | 2020-02-28 02:00:00 | 2020-02-28 02:59:59 | 1   |
| Cindy  | 2020-02-28 02:00:00 | 2020-02-28 02:59:59 | Cindy  | 2020-02-28 03:00:00 | 2020-02-28 03:36:59 | 1   |
+ ------ + ------------------- + ------------------- + ------ + ------------------- + ------------------- + --- +
```

P/S: Thanks to Strawberry for the table structure & data example.

**Edit:**
After Strawberry's comment, I agree that my previous query is not actually calculating the correct duration because I just take `TIMEDIFF` between `MAX(end_date)` and `MIN(start_date)`. I've made some changes and the updated query is below:

```
SELECT person,
       MIN(CASE WHEN starttime=0 THEN start_time ELSE starttime END) AS starttime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN endtime=0 THEN end_time ELSE endtime END) AS endtime,
       SUM(duration) AS duration,
       CASE WHEN starttime=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chk 
FROM
 (SELECT a.person, a.start_time,a.end_time,
         ANY_VALUE(CASE WHEN b.start_time > a.end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR THEN 0 
                        WHEN b.start_time IS NULL THEN a.start_time
                        ELSE a.start_time END) starttime,
         ANY_VALUE(CASE WHEN b.start_time > a.end_time + INTERVAL 1 HOUR THEN 0
                        WHEN b.start_time IS NULL THEN a.end_time
                        ELSE a.end_time END) endtime,
         TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.end_time,a.start_time)) duration
    FROM my_table a 
LEFT JOIN my_table b ON a.person=b.person AND b.start_time > a.end_time
GROUP BY a.person,a.start_time,a.end_time) TT
GROUP BY person,chk;
```

Here is the fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8XHWhfhCYSj8zcFcmo2KUo/1

P/S: I've added another 'Bob' record in the fiddle for testing purpose.

It's slightly similar to the previous one only this time I move most of the `ON` condition to `SELECT`. I also use `ANY_VALUE` to bypass the `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. On the other hand, if the `sql_mode` is turned off, `ANY_VALUE()` is not necessary. Note that in case you're using MariaDB, it doesn't support `ANY_VALUE()`.

Comment: I think this also fails to take 'correct' account of the situation where Cindy has another slot starting between 4.00 and 4.30